# Regex Image url

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to pre replace to get dynamic url,

Code is:

```
<span>
  <img src="/List/Detail/c0954c57-57ca-4f32-841d-de2b61a5087c/5358455" />
</span>
```

I need to extract: only `/List/Detail/c0954c57-57ca-4f32-841d-de2b61a5087c/5358455`

Ive tried: `\/Listing\/AdDetail\/`

Comment: Can you please modify your question and be so specific and clear about your requirement

Comment: _"I've tried"_ - Show us the complete attempt, not just a string in the middle of it. Btw, do you want to extract or replace the string? Your question is a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
preg_match("/<img src=\"(.*)\"/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

---

Use this regex to get the link between "*yourlink*"

```
(?<=")(.*)(?=")
```

Note: It works in PHP but not in Javascript. Lookbehind is not supported in Javascript!

Note 2: This answer is only specified for your SHORT information. I would suggest you to update your Question with more Details to get an better Code Sample!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Set<String> getImgStr(String htmlStr) {
    Set<String> pics = new HashSet<>();
    String img = "";
    Pattern p_image;
    Matcher m_image;
    String regEx_img = "<img.*src\\s*=\\s*(.*?)[^>]*?>";
    p_image = Pattern.compile
            (regEx_img, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    m_image = p_image.matcher(htmlStr);
    while (m_image.find()) {
        img = m_image.group();
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("src\\s*=\\s*\"?(.*?)(\"|>|\\s+)").matcher(img);
        while (m.find()) {
            pics.add(m.group(1));
        }
    }
    return pics;
}
```

Comment: Nice. Too bad the question was marked with PHP, though. =/